# Slicer in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-sheets-formula, add-on, slicers

I created a dashboard on Excel but want to move it to Google Sheets. How can I implement slicer like Excel on the spreadsheet?

I was using pivot in MS Excel with filters and slicers. I can replace slicer with some filters but in the spreadsheet, the filter isn't as handy as MS Excel and even dicer add-ons aren't functioning well. I am trying to replace it with data validation but that is making my dashboard extremely slow (Maybe because I can't find an efficient way). Can anyone suggest some combination of functions to create a slicer in Google spreadsheet? Any reading material recommendation regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Google Sheets, there are no Slicers but you can add an add-on to your Google Sheets called **[Dicers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dicers/icjfmhnohgcidkpalfpaoggofipahkek?utm_source=permalink)**

[image: 0]

see a demo here: **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uf9y4KZ3MAQ**

Answer (score 2):

For those who might land here after the question was originally answered:

Google Sheets now natively supports slicers.

Simply go to "Data" -> "Add a slicer" at the top menu.

See the documentation here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556