# Google Sheets: Enabling Slicers

Tags: google-sheets, slicers

It was announced on Aug 1st of this year that Slicers have been added to Google Sheets: https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/08/sheets-slicers-scorecards-themes.html.

This is supported by their updated docs here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9245556

I've selected my pivot table and went to `Data` and no slicer option was available:

[image]

---

In a tutorial video, [here](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slicers-in-google-sheets/), it shows the slicer should be there:

[image]

How do I enable to Slicer?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because slicers are now available for all Google Sheets users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when Google says it updates something it's usually meaning that the update process may take 15-30 days to roll out for all platforms starting with G Suit accounts and ending with regular Google accounts. Eg. the recommended course of action is to wait in this case.

if you want slicers right now, there is an addon: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/56914448/5632629**

> [image: 0]